# Opening multiple tabs in a browser

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to open 10 tabs of browsers from c# code, how could I do that?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var url in Getdata())
    {
        string URL = string.Format("http://www.websitename.com/member_id={0}", url.Replace("Member", ""));
        Response.Redirect(URL);
    }
}

public List<string> Getdata()
{
    List<string> Key = new List<string>();
    Key.Add("Member2942048");
    Key.Add("Member3271434");
    Key.Add("Member3271124");
    return Key;
}
```

Also suggest how to write jQuery / Javascript code for this (I could create arraylist in jQuery and read one by one)

Comment: This is a bad design, and I do not think that you can do that. If you can, then we can see pages that the old days open 10 windows with spams, to open 10 tabs with spams, and then 10 more and maybe why not 1000 tabs and crash the browser.

Comment: yes, i agree, but i want to open 10 tabs only, that's it, whether in c#,jquery,javascript

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you can use `Process.Start(websiteUrl );`

```
Process BrowserProcess = new Process();
```

like this:

```
ProcessStartInfo psiOjbect = new ProcessStartInfo("http://DefaultWebsiteOfmyCompany.com"); // You can also use "about:blank".

            BrowserProcess.StartInfo = psiOjbect;
            BrowserProcess.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(1000); //Need to wait 

            foreach (string websiteUrl in Properties.Settings.Default.WebSiteURLs)
            {
                Process.Start(websiteUrl );
            }
```

Comment: But this is NOT ASP .NET, this will open the browser on the computer on which it e is executed! Not the client. I don't think the OP meant this especially because it mentions JavaScript and jQuery. I'm surprised it's chosen as the answer.

Answer (score 6):

This will do the job:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Opens new window
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="page"></param>
    /// <param name="fullUrl"></param>
    public static void OpenNewWindow(System.Web.UI.Page page, string fullUrl, string key)
    {
        string script = "window.open('" + fullUrl + "', '" + key + "', 'status=1,location=1,menubar=1,resizable=1,toolbar=1,scrollbars=1,titlebar=1');";
        page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(page.GetType(), key, script, true);
    }
```

From your current page you should call something like this:

```
OpenNewWindow(this,"http://someServer/somePage.aspx","key");
```

Make sure your page contains ScriptManager and key is uniqe on every call!

So in your code:

```
int i=0;
string key = "Opener";
foreach (var url in Getdata())
{
     i +=1;
     string URL = string.Format("http://www.websitename.com/member_id={0}", url.Replace("Member", ""));
     OpenNewWindow(this,URL , key + i.ToString());
}
```

Comment: i could open only one popup window from this :( and it is last record from my list

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this from server side code.
what you can do is give the client a list of urls to open and then, let the client open new windows for each url. this could prove a little tricky since browsers my block you as windows spammer.

Comment: this is in the right direction. @idk, you need to reconsider your chosen answer. AMember, I think you should add more details.